# What does the number in codec section of YouTube "stats for nerds" mean

Tags: youtube

YouTube "stats for nerds" gives the information about the video being played. In the codec section it shows the mimetype and a number in bracket. What does this number mean.[image]

And how to get the latest Itag table for reference.

Comment: lets circle it so you can not read the text. ;)

Comment: Did you google: `video codec codes` ?

Comment: Sorry it says vp9(247) in the circle

Comment: Yeah I meant the video codec codes used in YouTube

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bit of searching I was able to figure it out myself

The number in brackets is the itag number for the codec + container + Profile combination. It is a unique number assigned by YouTube to identify different video types.

As for the latest itag table I was able to get it from Wikipedia.